# bash script: how to compare version numbers

Tags: bash, rpmbuild

I wrote a wrapper for rpmbuild that creates the source.tgz file in the `~/rpmbuild/SOURCES/`. However when I use this script on an older operating system; rpm's are built in `/usr/src/...`. So inside my bash script I would like to get the version number of rpmbuild; like this for example:

```
rpmbuild --version
```

which gives: `RPM version 4.11.1`. I'll get that into a variable; lets say

```
VERSION=4.11.1
```

Now how can I check easily inside my script that this is a version >=4.6.0 ? Do I really need to start parsing it into major, minor and bugfix and compare the three numbers, or is there another better way to do this? something like:

```
if [[ $VERSION >= 4.6.0 ]]
then
    # do stuff...
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the answer is not as simple as it may look like. Beside regular `MAJOR.MINOR.PATCHLEVEL` form any rpm also has `release` and sometimes `epoch` which takes precedence over version. Also as far as I remember different rpm-based Linux vendors have (or had in the past) a slightly different processing of ["corner cases"](http://blog.client9.com/2010/04/01/comparing-rpm-version-strings-rpm.html). So a technically correct answer should mention a specialized tool like [rpmvercmp](http://jnovy.fedorapeople.org/rpmvercmp.c) (this is one of *many* rpmvercmp implementations :) )